# Intersection check of a hyperplane and a hyper rectangle

Tags: geometry

Given a N-dimensional hyperplane and a N-dimensional hyper rectangle represented by its min point and max point, how to determine if they intersect?
A naive method by computing the intersection between edges of the hyper rectangle and the hyperplane gives a O(2^N) time complexity.
I wonder if this task can be finished in a more efficient way.

Comment: Sorry I haven't worked with higher dimensional geometries. What about projecting the rectangle's points onto the hyperplane and then testing the projected points for membership in the rectangle?

Comment: @Gene This will cause a exponential time regarding the number of dimension. I mange it with a linear programming now. But I did not find a geometric method.